# Starling detects button as Image

Tags: image, flash, button, actionscript, starling-framework

I have a class which is a screen, when I move the cursor, I'd like to detect what object is under it. I added a custom button of a the class TalentBtn which extends from starling's Button class, but when I trace it out it is an instance of the Image class. I can't cast it to a talenTbtn, when I try, it refers to null. I detect the objects with hitTest(point) method, which returns a DisplayObject. Do you guys think I can solve this problem somehow?
Here's the detecting method

```
private function onOverTalent(e:TouchEvent):void {
        var point:Point = new Point(e.getTouch(stage).globalX, e.getTouch(stage).globalY);
        
        displayObject = hitTest(point);
        if (displayObject == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        if (displayObject is Image) {
            talentFound = displayObject as TalentBtn;

            trace(displayObject);
            trace(talentFound);
        }
        
    }
```

The results of the traces are:

```
    [object Image]
    null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button is a subclass of DisplayObjectContainer, and when it is created it adds to itself an Image for the background and a TextField for the label (if any). Both of these are contained within a Sprite that is within the Button.

To specifically address what you're trying to do, try this:

```
private function onOverTalent(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    var point:Point = new Point(e.getTouch(stage).globalX, e.getTouch(stage).globalY);

    var hit:DisplayObject = hitTest(point);
    if (!hit)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Probably not a good idea, in case the interior structure of Button ever changes.
    var button:Button = hit.parent.parent as Button;
    trace(button);
    }
}
```

However, this approach has a problem: if the code inside of Button ever changes, it might break. So here's a more general approach:

```
private function onOverTalent(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    var point:Point = new Point(e.getTouch(stage).globalX, e.getTouch(stage).globalY);

    var hit:DisplayObject = hitTest(point);
    if (!hit)
    {
        return;
    }

    var button:Button;
    if (hit is Image || hit is TextField)
    {
        // Should be the containing Sprite now
        hit = hit.parent;
        while (hit)
        {
            button = hit as Button;

            if (button)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Go up one in the display hierarchy
            hit = hit.parent;
        }

        // None of it was a button.
        if (!button)
        {
            return;
        }

        // button will be the Button object at this point.
        trace(button);
    }
}
```

However, do you have a reason for not just listening for the `touch` event on the button itself?

http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/display/DisplayObject.html#event:touch

Comment: First of all, thanks for the good answer u made. Second, i did not wanted to add every button a new listener, i was pretty sure it wastes a lot of memory unneseccerly. Now i know it1s propaply not, but who cares after all ;)

Comment: @FerencDajka Particularly in Starling, the events are pooled and not liable to increase memory usage much if at all.